# MethodHandle - must be caught or declared to be thrown. Why this error?

Tags: java, exception

I have a Java 7 code, where I'm playing with [MethodHanlde](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html). The code is :

```
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;
class HelloWorldApp {
    public static  void main(String[] args) {
    MyMethodHandle obj = new MyMethodHandle();
    obj.getToStringMH();
    }
}

class MyMethodHandle {
    public String getToStringMH() {
        MethodHandle mh;
        String s ;
            MethodType mt = MethodType.methodType(String.class, char.class, char.class);
            MethodHandles.Lookup lk = MethodHandles.lookup();
        try {
            mh = lk.findVirtual(String.class, "replace", mt);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException mhx) {
            throw (AssertionError)new AssertionError().initCause(mhx);
        }
        try {
            s = (String) mh.invokeExact("daddy",'d','n');
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            throw (AssertionError)new AssertionError().initCause(e);
        }
        System.out.println(s);
        return "works";
    }
}
```

when I compile this :

```
javac HelloWorldApp.java
```

I get a error like this :

```
HelloWorldApp.java:23: error: unreported exception Throwable; must be caught or declared to be thrown
            s = (String) mh.invokeExact("daddy",'d','n');
                                       ^
1 error
```

Where I'm making mistake?

Comment: Instead of `(AssertionError)new AssertionError().initCause(mhx)` you can write `new AssertionError(mhx)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the Javadoc for [MethodHandle.invokeExact](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html#invokeExact%28java.lang.Object...%29) states

```
public final Object invoke(Object... args) throws Throwable
```

This means you must catch `Throwable` or declare your method `throws Throwable`.

BTW As this throws a generic exception an alternative to

```
    try {
        s = (String) mh.invokeExact("daddy",'d','n');
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        throw new AssertionError(t);
    }
```

is to rethrow the Throwable with

```
    try {
        s = (String) mh.invokeExact("daddy",'d','n');
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        Thread.currentThread().stop(t); // avoids wrapping the true exception
    }
```

While using Thread.stop(t) can be unpredictable if you stop another thread, it is predictable if you throw it for the current thread.

Note: You need to ensure your method "throws" the appropriate checked exception for the method you are calling as the compiler cannot ensure this is the case.

Comment: As explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) and in the [method docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28java.lang.Throwable%29), using `Thread.stop(Throwable)` is deprecated and is unsafe to use. Even for the current thread, its effects are unpredictable--e.g.: _"it may be used to generate exceptions that the target thread is unprepared to handle (including checked exceptions that the thread could not possibly throw, were it not for this method)"_

Comment: While you are correct, (Added a note) I don't see how obscuring the exception by wrapping it makes it any easier for the caller to catch the right exception. Its like saying, I don't know if you can catch this checked exception so I will make sure you can't.

Comment: In this case, it could throw a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` which unchecked and the caller might (unlikely) catch this exception. But if it wrapped with an `Error` or `RuntimeException`, this is made harder.

Answer (score 2):

`invokeExact` is declared `throws Throwable`. Thus, you need to catch `Throwable` instead of `Exception`. (An `Exception` is only one kind of `Throwable`.)

```
try {
    s = (String) mh.invokeExact("daddy",'d','n');
}
catch(Throwable t) {
    throw new AssertionError(t);
}
```